# Cannot login to the central administration, while the web applications are running well

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, central-administration

I am trying to connect to the central administration using the following URL 
`Servername:31546/`, but I will get the following error:

> Service Unavailable
>
> ---
>
> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

Baring in mind that all the web applications is working well, and users are able to access them without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

might be stupid or just a typo but:

```
http://Servername/31546
```

is wrong? shouldnt it be:

```
http://Servername:31546/
```

if its just a typo, please can you goto iis manager, look under "sites" you should see central amin within the list of sites, right click it and select "manage website" and then click on "browse". It should take you to the localhost of central admin:

or just copy pase this into the browser ;)

```
http://localhost:31546/
```

whats the result? if everything is correct than you should still run into the 503 error.

you could follow this, the person outlines 5 ways for fixing 503. In your case it could be:

> 5.The last fix I tried was perhaps AD related. Perhaps the Local Security settings had been modified domain wide so that only one
>   specific account had Allow Batch Logon rights. Perhaps the SP Farm
>   account, which is the account that runs the app pools, should be added
>   to the Allow Batch logon rights if it isn’t already there. I applied
>   the rights to the SP Farm account and this resolved the issue
>   completely.

http://potifar5000.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/http-error-503-service-unavailable-when-trying-to-open-central-administration-in-sharepoint-server-2010/

if that is also not the issue than you need to start looking at the sql server:

http://njbblog.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/error-sharepoint-2013-central.html

Tip: make sure that the app pool account password or user name hasnt changed! if in dout reenter the account details in iis manager for the central admin app pool account!

Comment: i miss typed the URL it is of course http://localhost:31546/

Comment: lol i thought so ;) as you would of got a 403 :) but have you made sure that your user account on the ca pool account is correct? like password hasnt expiered?

Comment: how i can chekc this as i can nto access the CA ??

Comment: goto iis manager got application pool, look for central admin application pool , clicking Advanced settings on the right hand side and re-enter the credentials in the Identity field!

Comment: you could just select prebuilt account and select networkservices to see if it works!

Comment: if its still a problem, goto central admin, under sites look for central admin site and click on it, on the right click basic settings.. you should get a box popup. click on test settings and tell me the outcome! on mine i have two ticks for my settings :) first one is for app pool and second is for virtual directory

Answer (score 3):

The error message is 503. So please check the Application pool in IIS. It might be stopped and hence you are getting this error. Start the associated Application pool.

Comment: i CA application pool is already started on IIS ..

Answer (score 1):

go, check the logfiles, check user which runs application pool. maybe changed password? user deactivated?